# Error: No available formula for php54-mcrypt on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: php, osx-mavericks, mcrypt

I am trying to install mcrypt PHP extension via Homebrew on Mac OS X Mavericks and get the following error.

`Error: No available formula for php54-mcrypt`

Help!

Comment: Not sure it helps, but I have `php54-mcrypt` installed via MacPort with no issues.

Comment: Yups, MacPort install process is smooth but this one was meant specifically for people trying to install it via Homebrew.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to run `brew tap homebrew/dupes` and then `brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php`

Then run `brew install php54-mcrypt` again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the correct directory. For example, you need to be in the homebrew directory if you run 'brew install php54-mcrypt'. If you're up one directory, you would need to run 'brew install homebrew/php54-mcrypt'.